# Multi target regression when some targets have correct NA labels

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, keras, regression, keypoint

I'm working on a Keras neural net that does key point prediction of body parts (left foot, left knee, left hip, etc.). For each image (X), the target (Y) is a list of coordinates for the keypoints (left_foot_x, left_foot_y, left_knee_x, left_knee_y), etc.). Whenever a keypoint isn't visible the X and Y coordinate equal = 0.

I suspect that leaving the data in this state will lead to bad results because 0 really means NA (i.e. the keypoint isn't visible). Leaving the X and Y coordinates 0 would suggest the keypoint is actually in the corner which is false. **What is the right way to structure data to do multi target regressions when the correct output is sometimes NA?**

Comment: What about using Python's None type? For example foo = None. 
foo, in this case, would be an object that has no value.

Comment: If the training data has targets that are equal to None, would during inference the model predict None type as well? That's the behavior I'd like to create..

Comment: I haven't tried training/predicting with None type labels, but I would think that the model should be able to predict Nones as long as Nones were included in your train labels. I did just think about the fact that None types could end up causing issues with calculating the loss on your model. I don't think Keras will be able to calculate the loss if some of your data is labeled with None types. In this case, you may see loss = NaN. Is it possible for you to instead use a number for non-visible key points that's guaranteed not to be used in your data set elsewhere, maybe like -1?

Comment: @blackHoleDetector you could use numbers but my guess is that would skew the results in a way you don't want them to. a value of -1 would be intepreted as being close to 0,1,2,3, etc. and far from larger numbers. but that's not what -1 represents.

Comment: Would probably make more sense to use two separate networks, since two separate tasks are being done. That way you're not artificially altering the data to affect the Loss, also I dont think None types work in the way being described

Comment: @megashigger any progress on the issue? I am facing similar use case ...